# Manual mocks with Jest -- I'm not understanding something

Tags: reactjs, api, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm learning jest, and trying to do a manual mock for an api, I'm missing something.

I'm mocking an api call to giphy. I'm seeing a lot of different syntaxes for the manual mocks, and unfortunately, they're not making much sense to me right now. I've been trying to code along with https://hackernoon.com/api-testing-with-jest-d1ab74005c0a and https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html, but I'm stuck.

I have a component called GifListContainer that displays 3 gifs, there's search functionality, I just want a manual mock with fake data to learn.

I'm using create-react-app, I see a lot of people using isomorphic-fetch and other packages, but since jest is built in can't I do it without adding anything else?

I can't figure out how to manually write the mock, I feel I'm missing something simple. It's testing fine if I don't use the mock (using different testing syntax because I'm not testing the _ *mock* _ file). Thank you for your time.

The error I'm getting:

```
  ● should load gifs
    TypeError: GifContainer.api is not a function
      at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/Part_2/GifContainer.test.js:10:23)
  ✕ should load gifs (6ms)
```

GifListContainer.js

```
import {gifApi} from './api'
class GifListContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    gifs: []
  };  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.displayGifs('coding');
  } 
  displayGifs = (query) => {
    gifApi(query)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        let firstThreeGifs = json.data.slice(0, 3);
        let urls = firstThreeGifs.map(
          gif => gif.images.original.url.split("?")[0]
        );
        this.setState({
          gifs: [...urls]
        });
      });
  };
    //after this there's a search function and the render and such.
```

api.js

```
const urlPartOne = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q="
const urlPartTwo = "&api_key=UE0dCN2WofIwVF0RPbpHo0Lz0k9VhqdG"
const gifApi = (query) => {
  return fetch(urlPartOne + query + urlPartTwo)
}
export {gifApi}
```

GifContainer.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
let mockFunction = jest.mock('./api.js');
import * as GifContainer from './GifContainer';
it('should load gifs', () => {
  return GifContainer.displayGifs('sunshine')
  .then(data => {
  expect(data).toBeDefined()
  expect(data.entity.data.type).toEqual('gif')
  })
})
```

_ *mocks* _/api.js
I'm really just not getting how to write this.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const api = (query) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
fs.readFile(`./src/Part_2/__mockData__/query.json`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
if (err) reject(err)
  resolve({ entity: JSON.parse(data) })
  })
})
export default api
```

and then mock data in a folder _ *mockData* _/sushine.json

```
/* http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=sunshine&api_key=UE0dCN2WofIwVF0RPbpHo0Lz0k9VhqdG */
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "gif",
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK",
    "response_id": "5b11716a33554c732e0ddf42"
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so the problem is on the mock itself.
  Actually, first of all you need to improve the way you are doing react unit testing.

Nowadays, there are tools like Enzyme(http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) which helps you a lot to test React components.

Have you check the Testing React Apps section for Jest? Specially the DOM Testing part? Take a look here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#dom-testing

Back to your problem, I think it's because you are exporting the fn as default in the mock file but haven't done that on the api file. Try to put both equals and let me know!

Comment: Hi, thank you! I'll look into that for testing how elements are rendered on the dom, but I'm still just trying to focus on how to do manual mocks right now. Error message remains the same (I realize I gave you the slightly wrong error message before, my apologies, from what I read I'm supposed to be using the same .method call as named in my component): 

`    TypeError: GifContainer.displayGifs is not a function
      
      at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/Part_2/GifContainer.test.js:16:23)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7`

Comment: okay.. Focusing only on the error... The error is because the `GifContainer` is a class, so, you need to instantiate it first.. something like `container = new GifContainer()` then you can call `container.displayGifs` however this is far from being the right way to test React components...

To remove the first steps to test a React component, what about import the api file into a dumb module and test it there?  

You can create a new javascript module with a silly function to call the api.js. It will be easier to test and you will not be impacted by any React error